# How to convert the UTC time to Shanghai +8 timezone time in template?

Tags: python, django

From the database, I query out the created_date and put in the template:

[image]

You see, it is UTC time, how can I in the template shows the +8 timezone time?

I tried use the custom template-filter to change, but failed:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import datetime, time

register = template.Library()

### function

def utc2local(utc_st):
   """UTC时间转本地时间（+8:00)"""
   now_stamp = time.time()
   local_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now_stamp)
   utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(now_stamp)
   offset = local_time - utc_time
   local_st = utc_st + offset

   return local_st


@register.filter
def convert_utc_to_shanghai(value):
    """
    UTC->Shanghai
    :param value:
    :return:
    """

    local_time = utc2local(value)

    print local_time.strftime("% Y - % m - % d % H: % M: % S")

    return local_time.strftime
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: My custom filter seems not work, I have edited my post.

Comment: Have you tried django's [`timezone` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone)?

Comment: Working with timezones can be an absolute nightmare, particularly because of things like Daylight Saving zones. Might not so bad if only working with two timezones, but usually it is advisable to use some kind of timezone library. You could take a look at http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @schwobaseggl It seems not work. Still the value.

Answer (score 3):

my solution is does not save utc time to db,set this in settings.py:

```
# Chinese Shanghai
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hans'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
# db does not use utc time
USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: It also worked for my Django setting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1: *timezone.localtime*

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hans'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
USE_TZ = True
```

$ ./manage.py shell

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from django.utils import timezone

In [2]: timezone.now()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 12, 57, 8, 32455, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [3]: timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 20, 57, 18, 743225, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' CST+8:00:00 STD>)
```

templatetags

```py
@register.filter
def convert_utc_to_shanghai(value):
    return f'{timezone.localtime(value):% Y - % m - % d % H: % M: % S}'
```

## solution 2:  *pytz*

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

import pytz


def beijing_time(dt: Optional[datetime], fmt: str = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") -> str:
    """将datetime类型转化为北京时间的字符串，精确到秒
    Example::
        >>> from datetime import datetime; from django.utils import timezone
        >>> beijing_time(datetime.now())
        '2021-06-30 16:37:40'
        >>> beijing_time(datetime.utcnow())
        '2021-06-30 16:38:18'
        >>> now = timezone.now()
        >>> print(now)
        2021-06-30 08:42:49.838529+00:00
        >>> beijing_time(now)
        '2021-06-30 16:42:49'

    """
    if dt is None:
        return ""
    return f"{dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')):{fmt}}"
```

templatetags

```py
@register.filter
def convert_utc_to_shanghai(value):
    return beijing_time(value)
```